# SQL How to get max token of varbinary(max)?

Tags: sql, image, hsqldb

I am just working with the HSQL database on `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb`.
I started learning SQL today. Now I am trying to add a column to a table of books, giving the book covers. The problem: If I try with `varbinary(max)` I get the error:

> unexpected token: MAX

If do the same with a fixed value like 1000 it works. But I don't know if that's the right value. So, how do I get the max variable?

Comment: Can you post your entire SQL statement? It could be syntax, or a reserved word (max is a function in SQL), or some other issue.

Comment: use LONGVARBINARY... source http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_binary_types

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hsqldb/hsqldb_data_types.htm) page, the maximum length for `varbinary` is 8000:

```
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| Data Type | Description                                                 |
|-----------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
| varbinary | Maximum length of 8,000 bytes (Variable length binary data) |
\-----------|-------------------------------------------------------------/
```